# Angular Material button to clear entire form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Is it possible to clear/reset a form with a single button? The form contains material datepicker, input, textarea, select and checkboxes.

My actual code:

```
  <form class="example-form" #form="ngForm">
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary (click)="clear(form.value)">Clear</button>
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput placeholder="Name" name="name" ngModel>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="birthday" [(ngModel)]="geburtsdatum" placeholder="Geburtsdatum" name="geburtsdatum">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="birthday"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #birthday></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="unlimited" name="unbegrenzt">unlimited</mat-checkbox>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select placeholder="Transpondertyp" name="transponderTyp" [(ngModel)]="form.transponderTyp">
        <mat-option>None</mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let transponderTyp of transponderTyps" [value]="transponderTyp.value">
          {{ transponderTyp.viewValue }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Best regards

Comment: you can use form.reset()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<button (click)="form.reset()" >RESET</button>`

use reset() method of TD form

Answer (score 2):

Suhag's solution should work, although I would always specify the button type so it is not treated as a submit button:

```
<button type="button"(click)="form.reset()">Reset</button>
```

Otherwise you could simply do this:

```
<button type="reset">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear the model on the click event:

```
 <form class="example-form" #form="ngForm">
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary (click)="clear(form.value)">Clear</button>
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput placeholder="Name" name="name" ngModel>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="birthday" [(ngModel)]="geburtsdatum" placeholder="Geburtsdatum" name="geburtsdatum">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="birthday"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #birthday></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="unlimited" name="unbegrenzt">unlimited</mat-checkbox>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select placeholder="Transpondertyp" name="transponderTyp" [(ngModel)]="form.transponderTyp">
        <mat-option>None</mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let transponderTyp of transponderTyps" [value]="transponderTyp.value">
          {{ transponderTyp.viewValue }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
   <button (click)="resetForm()" >RESET</button>
  </form>
```

component:

```
resetForm() {
  this.geburtsdatum = '';
  this.unlimited = '';
  this.form.transponderTyp = '';
  this.transponderTyp.value = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing to `ngForm` directive into the component you would be able to use:

`ngForm.resetForm()`

Checkout this example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Fbb9QQQBI2sWF6mdrcNU?p=preview